# How to install Node.js, npm, socket.io and use them?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I am newbie to Node.js
Can someone explain me how can I install Node.js, npm and socket.io step by step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1.. Go to http://nodejs.org and click on Install button

2.. Download node and install it

3.. Create an empty folder on your hard disk

4.. Create an package.json file with the following content

```
{
    "name": "App",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "App",
    "dependencies": {
        "socket.io": "latest"
    },
    "author": "developer"
}
```

5.. Open windows's command prompt (press Windows key + R and type *cmd*)

6.. Navigate to your newly created directory with *cd* command

7.. Type *npm install* in that directory

8.. Wait till everything is downloaded and installed

9.. Create a file app.js with the following content:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(3000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

10.. Create a file index.html with the following content

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

11.. Again, go to the command prompt (console) and type *node app.js*. This will run nodejs server and you may open *localhost:3000*

Comment: Thanks, but when I type "npm install" in cmd, this error happens: "npm" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @aliA Seems like npm isn't correctly on the path as it is installed with, and next to, node.

Comment: Hm ... that's strange. And this happen even after the nodejs installation. Normally Node for windows adds npm to the global PATH.

Comment: thanks, I needed to install npm in nodejs installation directory first, It's working now. Now I need to find a simple example of making a chat or real time notification by nodejs.  Well thank you so much mr Krasimir.

Comment: You may find this helpful http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Real-time-chat-with-NodeJS-Socketio-and-ExpressJS

Answer (score 6):

**1. Install Node.js and NPM (Node Package Manager) on your local machine.**

Windows installers are available at http://www.nodejs.org/. Simply download the relevant installer, and double-click it to get it working on your machine. You can verify that node is correctly installed by double-clicking the node.exe file in the installation directory, and running any Javascript commands. If you can type in "1+1" and get the resulting "2", then Node is running properly.

Since you installed Node using an installer, NPM is already installed. If you compiled Node from source installation however, then you'll have to install NPM separately. You can find instructions for that at http://www.npmjs.org/.

If your NPM is correctly installed you'll get the following output when you type `npm` in command prompt from your root directory:

```
where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, la, link, list, ll,
    ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix, prune,
    publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, restart, rm, root,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap, star,
    start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, version, view,
    whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview
```

**2. Run the install package.**

Now that you've successfully setup Node and NPM, you can run the install command that you found on the socket.io website. Simply make sure that you're running NPM from the command line. That will download and install the package on your local machine.

Comment: thanks, i installed node.js successfully and also tried 1+1 with node.exe in nodejs directory and it works well. but on windows cmd, npm does not work. following error happens: "npm" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Did you install Node using the `.msi` installer for Windows?

Comment: So then (if you just clicked your way through the installation without making any custom changes), NPM is already installed on your system. You just have to access it properly. So try this: 1. Run the command prompt pressing the Windows Key + R on your keyboard, typing `cmd` into the prompt, and pressing Enter. 2. Locate the folder where your node installation resides on your computer and navigate your way there by using command prompt. This can be done by typing out something like `cd directory1/directory2/node/`. --> continued

Comment: 3. Once you're in the directory where node is installed, just type `npm`. Then you should get the screen output I posted above, indicating a working installation of NPM. Let me know how that goes. :)

Comment: yes, i got the screen you posted above. so should I run npm install in this directory?

Comment: Now follow the #2 part in my post; yes. When you're finished with that, you can return to the post from @Krasimir and get socket.io setup.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37978/discussion-between-shmuli-and-ali-a)

Comment: If my answer was of help to you, please be sure to upvote. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), npm is their package manager (Node Package Manager).

Edit: If you don't understand Node.js here is a quick overview:

1. Create a text file ("app.js") and install the dependencies ("npm install socket.io")
2. Paste the code from socket.io
3. save and run (in the folder: "node app.js")