# WebRTC RTCMultiConnection using Socket IO

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I started R&D on WebRTC with socket io. I followed this [tutorial](https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Scalable-Broadcast.html) . downloaded this [project](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast) from GitHub, Installed socket io by following these steps [install socket io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990494/how-to-install-node-js-npm-socket-io-and-use-them/18991258#18991258)

Now after running index.html, on click of open or join broadcast button, button gets disabled but nothing happens and there's no errors in console also

[image: WebRTC]

index.html code:

```
<input type="text" id="broadcast-id" placeholder="broadcast-id" value="room-xyz">
<select id="broadcast-options">
    <option>Audio+Video</option>
    <option title="Works only in Firefox.">Audio+Screen</option>
    <option>Audio</option>
    <option>Video</option>
    <option title="Screen capturing requries HTTPs. Please run this demo on HTTPs to make sure it can capture your screens.">Screen</option>
</select>
<button id="open-or-join">Open or Join Broadcast</button>
<hr>
<div id="videos-container"></div>

<script src="http://10.0.0.***:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://10.0.0.***');

    // using single socket for RTCMultiConnection signaling
    var onMessageCallbacks = {};
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        if (data.sender == connection.userid) return;
            if (onMessageCallbacks[data.channel]) {
                onMessageCallbacks[data.channel](data.message);
            };
        });

    // initializing RTCMultiConnection constructor.
    function initRTCMultiConnection(userid) {
        var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
        connection.body = document.getElementById('videos-container');
        connection.channel = connection.sessionid = connection.userid = userid || connection.userid;
        connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
            OfferToReceiveAudio: false,
            OfferToReceiveVideo: true
        };
        // using socket.io for signaling
        connection.openSignalingChannel = function(config) {
            var channel = config.channel || this.channel;
            onMessageCallbacks[channel] = config.onmessage;
            if (config.onopen) setTimeout(config.onopen, 1000);
            return {
                send: function(message) {
                    socket.emit('message', {
                        sender: connection.userid,
                        channel: channel,
                        message: message
                    });
                },
                channel: channel
           };
      };
      connection.onMediaError = function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      };
      return connection;
 }

 // this RTCMultiConnection object is used to connect with existing users
 var connection = initRTCMultiConnection();

 connection.getExternalIceServers = false;

 connection.onstream = function(event) {
     connection.body.appendChild(event.mediaElement);

     if (connection.isInitiator == false && !connection.broadcastingConnection) {
          // "connection.broadcastingConnection" global-level object is used
          // instead of using a closure object, i.e. "privateConnection"
          // because sometimes out of browser-specific bugs, browser 
          // can emit "onaddstream" event even if remote user didn't attach any stream.
          // such bugs happen often in chrome.
          // "connection.broadcastingConnection" prevents multiple initializations.

          // if current user is broadcast viewer
          // he should create a separate RTCMultiConnection object as well.
          // because node.js server can allot him other viewers for
          // remote-stream-broadcasting.
          connection.broadcastingConnection = initRTCMultiConnection(connection.userid);

          // to fix unexpected chrome/firefox bugs out of sendrecv/sendonly/etc. issues.
          connection.broadcastingConnection.onstream = function() {};

          connection.broadcastingConnection.session = connection.session;
          connection.broadcastingConnection.attachStreams.push(event.stream); // broadcast remote stream
          connection.broadcastingConnection.dontCaptureUserMedia = true;

          // forwarder should always use this!
          connection.broadcastingConnection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
               OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
               OfferToReceiveAudio: false
          };

          connection.broadcastingConnection.open({
               dontTransmit: true
          });
      }
 };

 // ask node.js server to look for a broadcast
 // if broadcast is available, simply join it. i.e. "join-broadcaster" event should be emitted.    
 // if broadcast is absent, simply create it. i.e. "start-broadcasting" event should be fired.
 document.getElementById('open-or-join').onclick = function() {
       var broadcastid = document.getElementById('broadcast-id').value;
       if (broadcastid.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length <= 0) {
            alert('Please enter broadcast-id');
            document.getElementById('broadcast-id').focus();
            return;
       }

       this.disabled = true;

       connection.session = {
            video: document.getElementById('broadcast-options').value.indexOf('Video') !== -1,
            screen: document.getElementById('broadcast-options').value.indexOf('Screen') !== -1,
            audio: document.getElementById('broadcast-options').value.indexOf('Audio') !== -1,
            oneway: true
      };

      socket.emit('join-broadcast', {
          broadcastid: broadcastid,
          userid: connection.userid,
          typeOfStreams: connection.session
      });
};

// this event is emitted when a broadcast is already created.
socket.on('join-broadcaster', function(broadcaster, typeOfStreams) {
    connection.session = typeOfStreams;
    connection.channel = connection.sessionid = broadcaster.userid;

    connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
        OfferToReceiveVideo: !!connection.session.video,
        OfferToReceiveAudio: !!connection.session.audio
    };

    connection.join({
        sessionid: broadcaster.userid,
        userid: broadcaster.userid,
        extra: {},
        session: connection.session
    });
});

// this event is emitted when a broadcast is absent.
socket.on('start-broadcasting', function(typeOfStreams) {
     // host i.e. sender should always use this!
     connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
          OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
          OfferToReceiveAudio: false
     };
     connection.session = typeOfStreams;
     connection.open({
         dontTransmit: true
     });

     if (connection.broadcastingConnection) {
         // if new person is given the initiation/host/moderation control
         connection.broadcastingConnection.close();
         connection.broadcastingConnection = null;
     }
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     // Firefox is weird!
     document.getElementById('open-or-join').disabled = false;
};
</script>
```

I am newbie to this, what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I myself was stuck in the same situation a while ago. I wanted to implement somewhat similar algorithm as Muaz had done in his git repo but many places i found that this repo of Muaz is now not maintained and is outdated and i had to start from scratch. So I just followed Shane Tully's webRTC example and started to code my algorithm on top of it. 
Stream is relayed over clients as in the muaz's algorithm but algorithm is modified to form a torrent chain. The implemented algorithm is [here(git repo)](https://github.com/akshat7101999/WebRTC-scalable-broadcast-p2p) --
[and the algorithm is as shown in figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNXLF.jpg)

High Bandwidth and Low Bandwidth Clients are filtered so that only High Bandwidth clients act as stream forwarders. It works great on LAN and on internet it has quite some room for improvement.